Looking for an older (80's or 90's) war movie
I'm looking for the name of a 80's or 90's war movie, but there is only one scene I can clearly remember, and it went something like this :
A solider is being held within what looks to be a bamboo made jail
cell, and he's in very rough shape. Another solider (a guard) walks up
to him smoking a cigarette. Confusingly enough, I think these two are
actually on the same "side". 
He puts the cigarette in the prisoners mouth, and he begins talking
about how his commander or general has "big plans for him", the line
goes something like, "But you man... the commanders got big plans for
you man!" While the guard is talking, the prisoner's face remains
completely expressionless, and the cigarette just continues to burn slowly.
Basically the camera just pans between the guard's face (who is the only one with any dialogue in the scene), and the prisoner's face.
I also remember a tribe of indigenous people (Amazonian?) being depicted in one of the following scenes, but I could be wrong.
Does anyone know what the name of this movie is?

This is Apocalypse Now (1979). The scene is late in the movie. The speaker is a reporter played by Dennis Hopper. The man in the cage is Martin Sheen.



At the very end of the above scene, he says "YOU" and is pointing. The following dialog is where he says "... he's got plans for you"

excellent movie BTW. Avoid "redux" version.

Yes! This is definitely it - thank you sir!

side note: the original release of this movie had no credits and no previews. My father saw it in the theater and it just started and then ended. The credits were on a sheet of paper.

@Yorik why avoid redux? It's long as hell but is there another specific reason some people prefer standard version?

Well, I don't think I am alone in thinking this, but it really is a matter of opinion. Less is More. The scenes really add nothing and there is a plantation scene that, in my opinion, is such a mood killer that it comes close to destroying the good will built up to that point. Never Get Off the Boat. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbFvAaO9j8M
